# apply seach criteria to whole cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am trying to use MATCH() and/or LOOKUP() in LibreOffice Calc. I have the "Search criteria = and <> must apply to whole cells" and the "Enable regular expressions in formulas" options selected. The item I am looking for is a multi word string.

How do I provide a search criteria as a cell reference (E3) in to LOOKUP(E3, B1:B20, C1:C20) and have it match the value in B1:B20 EXACTLY? Right now it is matching partial strings rather than matching the cell values exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it is a late answer, I've had difficulties myself to accomplish what OP asked, so just for the record:

Go to "Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Calculate" and:

- switch on the option "Search criteria = and <> must apply to whole cells".
- switch off the option "Enable regular expressions in formulas" if you have cell contents with () or other characters which are interpreted as regular expressions. Taking this option off causes the comparison to be performed against full exact text.

Hope it helps.